# How do the words in the search append as in Google

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I write "video "
and I is added to the drop-down list:

```
video converter  
video saver 
video player
```

Ho do this?
I just know that every time the asp.net page reloads, but I need without overloading.

Comment: Are you talking about an auto-completing text box? Something that returns matching results as a user types?

Comment: Hi Google a bit about "auto completion" and ajax page rendering / refresh

Comment: You'd need some sort of javascript function that pulls up common related queries.  It may or may not require AJAX.

Comment: The term you are looking for is **autocomplete**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [Autocomplete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) script. Microsoft's [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) provides that.

And there's also a [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Here are some tutorials on the subject:

#### Microsoft's:

- http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/using-autocomplete-in-the-ajax-toolkit/
- http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-autocomplete-extender-using-asp-net-c/

#### jQuery's

- [jQuery Autocomplete and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net)
- [JQuery AutoComplete plugin in ASP.Net page with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631226/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-in-asp-net-page-with-c)

I will have the decency of not copying the code from those to here `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about something called AutoComplete.  To implement this functionality you will need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).  In ASP.NET there are two popular ways to accomplish this:

- [The AJAX toolkit from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)
- [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

I personally prefer jQuery because it feels more lightweight/intuitive than what Microsoft offers, but I would recommend looking at both and seeing what you are more comfortable with.  The AJAX toolkit is more integrated with Visual Studio so many people prefer using this...